# Using GREP and Regex to find repeating positional patterns in text

Tags: regex, grep

I am trying to solve a cipher puzzle where all characters have been replaced by non-alphanumeric symbols.

I am trying to use `grep` and the dictionary to find words that might match patterns in the cipher.

I for example, let's assume I have the following word in my puzzle:

```
@&!*&;?
```

I want to use grep to search the dictionary for 7-letter words that contain the same letter in the 2nd and 5th places, exclusively.

I assume grep has to be able to do this, but I haven't been able to figure out how.

Comment: Use capture groups and back-references.

Comment: https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> search the dictionary for 7-letter words that contain the same letter in the 2nd and 5th places, exclusively

With GNU grep and a back reference:

```
grep -E '^.(.)..\1..$' file
```

Output with [this wordlist](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/powerlanguage/word-lists/master/common-7-letter-words.txt) (first 15 lines):

```
Airlift
Airline
Airsick
Airtime
Alfalfa
Alkalic
Antenna
Antonym
Badland
Baggage
Bandage
Bandaid
Bargain
Bastard
Believe
```

---

See: `man grep` and [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Answer (score 0):

I thought it might be of interest to suggest some code that could be used to test words against arbitrary patterns. The code below is written in Ruby, but I've made it very simple and commented it heavily, so one should be able to convert it to most any general-purpose language quite easily.

I will first define a helper method that converts a word pattern to a hash that makes it easy to determine if a given word matches the pattern.

```
def repeats_map(pattern)
  # create an empty hash that maps the first appearance of a char in
  # pattern to its index in the string
  chars_to_idx = {}              

  # create an empty hash that maps, for each char that is a repeat, its
  # index i in pattern to the index of the first occurrence of the char
  # in pattern
  repeats = {}

  # loop through indices of chars in pattern
  (0..pattern.size-1).each do |i|
    # extract char at offset i in pattern
    c = pattern[i]
    # see if c has already been seen
    if chars_to_idx.key?(c)
      # specify that char at offset i equals at offset chars_to_idx[c]
      repeats[i] = chars_to_idx[c]
    else
      # add c=>i key-value pair to # add c=>i key-value pair to h
      chars_to_idx[c] = i
    end
  end
  # return repeats
  repeats
end
```

This method should become more clear by computing a few examples.

```
repeats_map("@&!*&;?")      #=> {4=>1}
repeats_map("@&!*&;?&")     #=> {4=>1, 7=>1}
repeats_map("@&!*&;;&")     #=> {4=>1, 6=>5, 7=>1} 
repeats_map("@&!*&@;?!&!*") #=> {4=>1, 5=>0, 8=>2, 9=>1, 10=>2, 11=>3}
```

If the first pattern (`"@&!*&;?"`) applies, a word (of length `"@&!*&;?".size #=> 7`) matches the pattern if its character at index `4` equals its character at index `1`. For example, "sandals" matches, whereas "sundial" does not. For the second pattern, the word's characters at indexes `4` and `7` must both equal the character at index `1`.

We can now write a method to determine if a given word matches a given pattern.

```
def word_matches?(word, pattern)
  return false if word.size != pattern.size

  # obtain repeats hash from pattern
  repeats = repeats_map(pattern)

  # convert all chars of word to lower case
  w = word.downcase

  # loop over each character index in word to determine if a condition
  # is true for all indices     
  (0..w.size-1).all? do |i|
     # return true for index i if repeats does not have a key i or if
     # does have a key i and the char at index i of word equals the
     # char at index repeats[i] of word; else return false
     repeats.key?(i) == false || w[i] == w[repeats[i]]
  end
end
```

Suppose

```
pattern = "@&@*&?"
```

so that

```
pattern.size                       #=> 6
repeats_map(pattern)               #=> {2=>0, 4=>1}
```

```
word_matches?("avarve",  pattern)  #=> true 
word_matches?("dodroe",  pattern)  #=> true 
word_matches?("avarves", pattern)  #=> false 
word_matches?("avarv",   pattern)  #=> false 
word_matches?("avarwe",  pattern)  #=> false 
word_matches?("averve",  pattern)  #=> false
```

Some readers may not be familiar with the words "avarve" and "dodroe" but I've used both in Scrabble without being challenged, so I believe they are actual words.